# variable still empty after the loop problem in shell scripting

Tags: loops, string, shell

I'm very new in shell scripting, and I encountered a problem that is quite wired. The program is rather simple so I just post it here:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=""

list=`mtx -f /dev/sg2 status | while read status
do
    result=$(echo ${status} | grep "Full")
    if [ -z "$result" ]; then
        continue
    else
       echo $(echo ${result} | cut -f3 -d' ' | tr -d [:alpha:] | tr -d [:punct:])
    fi
done`

echo ${list}

for haha in ${list}
do
    printf "current slot is:%s \n" ${haha}
done
```

What the program does is that it executes `mtx -f /dev/sg2 status` and goes to each line and see if there's a full disk. If it has "Full" in that line, I'll record the slot number in that line, and put in the `list`.

Notice that I put a back quote after `list=` at line 6, and it covers the whole "while" loop after that. The reason is unclear to me, but I got this usage by just googling it. It is said that the while loop will open up a separate shell or something like that, so when the while loop is done, whatever you concatenated in the loop will get lost, so in my initial implementation, `list` is still empty after the while loop.

My question is: even if the code above works fine, it looks pretty tricky to others, and what's worse, I can only make only ONE `list` after the loop is done. Is there a better way to fix this so that I can pull out more information from the loop? Like what if I need `list2` to store other values? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell script does work. If you wanted to get two pieces of info per line insteal of one, you would have to change this line

```
echo $(echo ${result} | cut -f3 -d' ' | tr -d [:alpha:] | tr -d [:punct:])
```

to concatenate the desired values separated by a comma or any other "special" character. Then you could parse your list this way :

```
for haha in ${list}
do
   printf "current slot is:%s, secondary info:%s \n" $(echo ${haha} | cut -f1 -d',') $(echo ${haha} | cut -f2 -d',')
done
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this explanation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). As a pipe is involved, the `while read...` code isn't executed in your current shell, but in a subshell (A child process which can't update your current process' (environment/shell) variables).

Choose on of the listed workarounds to make the `while read...` loop execute in your current shell.